# How to get list of functions inside a DLL (managed and unmanaged)?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, unmanaged

So I play around a DLL (UnityEditor.dll) I wanna to get a list of all functions inside of this managed DLL which are unmanaged (dll is probably composed from a native C++ (with statically compiled libaries if such were used) core and managed C++ wrapper all wrapped into one dll.) I want to get a list of all unmanaged functions inside of that Dll to for example create my own managed\unmanaged wrapper?

Comment: Do you mean the exports?

Comment: say functions that were defined as `extern C ...` or something like that

Comment: The UnityEditor.dll is a managed dll, and all it does is wrap calls to Unity's C++ code. You can view its code using dotPeek.

Answer (score 17):

The [`dumpbin.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) utility shipped with Visual Studio can be used to display a list of exports. For example:

> dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS C:\WINDOWS\System32\Kernel32.dll

Example output:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for KERNEL32.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    4E20FBA0 time date stamp Sat Jul 16 03:46:56 2011
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
        1390 number of functions
        1390 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0          AcquireSRWLockExclusive (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlAcquireSRWLockExclusive)
          2    1          AcquireSRWLockShared (forwarded to NTDLL.RtlAcquireSRWLockShared)
          3    2 00004440 ActivateActCtx
          4    3 00066B80 AddAtomA
          5    4 00066B20 AddAtomW
          6    5 0006ADF0 AddConsoleAliasA
          7    6 0006AE60 AddConsoleAliasW
```

Comment: all I get from it is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>dumpbin.exe /EXPORTS "C:\Program Files (x86)\ppp \UnityEngine.dll"
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file C:\Program Files (x86)\ppp\UnityEngine.dll

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
       74000 .text

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>

Comment: @myWallJSON, then there are no functions exported by that DLL. You could investigate the other options to `dumpbin`.

Comment: even "ALL" does not provide any info.  the unmanaged DLL is wrapped inside a native one=(

Answer (score 2):

Open the .dll file and look for the EXPORT section of this PE file using the binary PE/COFF specs [available from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463125.aspx).

But that's an overkill, I think. Your question should be a concrete want. What exactly do you want to wrap and what do you have ? Only the binaries and no source/headers ?

Answer (score 1):

DLLs don't contain "functions".  They contain code and entrypoints.  It's not possible to tell from optimized code where transitions between functions occur unless you have a debug database.